# Mod Rewrite in order to have SEO Friendly URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make seo friendly URLs with .htaccess mod rewrite, but I have a problem - when I'm trying to access the "new page" it returns me a 404 error. I searched a lot, but the rule seems to be wrote well for me.

I have something like *site.com/work/index.php?page=something* and I want to change it to *site.com/work/something*

The rule which I'm using is:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\$ /work/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Thank you for your time!
All best regards.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^work/([^/]+)$ /work/index.php?page=$1 [L]`?

Comment: escaped $ , remove the backslash before $ in your rules pattern, otherwise engine will match it literally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^work/(.*)$ /work/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```